# How to get ° character in a string in python?

Tags: python, string

How can I get a `°` (degree) character into a string?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37678518/4099593) if you are attempting to print the degree sign on a ***Windows*** system.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Put this line at the top of your source

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If your editor uses a different encoding, substitute for utf-8

Then you can include utf-8 characters directly in the source

Comment: Assuming your editor does UTF-8. If your editor uses a different charset then indicate that instead.

Answer (score 116):

This is the most coder-friendly version of specifying a Unicode character:

```
degree_sign = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
```

**Escape Sequence:** `\N{name}`

**Meaning:** Character named *name* in the Unicode database

**Reference:** https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

**Note:**

- "N" must be uppercase in the `\N` construct to avoid confusion with the `\n` newline character
- The character name inside the curly braces can be any case

It's easier to remember the [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) of a character than its Unicode index. It's also more readable, ergo debugging-friendly. The character substitution happens at compile time, i.e. the `.py[co]` file will contain a constant for `u'°'`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> c= compile('u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}"', '', 'eval')
>>> dis.dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (u'\xb0')
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> c.co_consts
(u'\xb0',)
>>> c= compile('u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}-\N{EMPTY SET}"', '', 'eval')
>>> c.co_consts
(u'\xb0-\u2205',)
>>> print c.co_consts[0]
°-∅
```

Answer (score 50):

```
>>> u"\u00b0"
u'\xb0'
>>> print _
°
```

BTW, all I did was search "unicode degree" on Google. This brings up two results:
"Degree sign U+00B0" and "Degree Celsius U+2103", which are actually different:

```
>>> u"\u2103"
u'\u2103'
>>> print _
℃
```

Comment: Or just `a = '\u00b0'` in Python 3.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Well yeah, but I didn't remember the numpad code for ° and didn't feel like looking it up at the time.

Comment: Who remembers numpad codes? :)  [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) sequences are a _lot_ easier to remember; degree is just Compose-o-o. Compose key is standard on X windows systems, but it's also available for Microsoft Windows; see the Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use `chr(176)` to print the degree sign.
Here is an example using python 3.6.5 interactive shell:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spoWL.png]

Answer (score 13):

just use `\xb0 (in a string);` python will convert it automatically

Answer (score 12):

Above answers assume that UTF8 encoding can safely be used - this one is specifically targetted for Windows.

The Windows console normaly uses CP850 encoding and **not** utf-8, so if you try to use a source file utf8-encoded, you get those 2 (incorrect) characters `┬░` instead of a degree `°`.

Demonstration (using python 2.7 in a windows console):

```
deg = u'\xb0`  # utf code for degree
print deg.encode('utf8')
```

effectively outputs `┬░`.

Fix: just force the correct encoding (or better use unicode):

```
local_encoding = 'cp850'    # adapt for other encodings
deg = u'\xb0'.encode(local_encoding)
print deg
```

or if you use a source file that explicitely defines an encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
local_encoding = 'cp850'  # adapt for other encodings
print " The current temperature in the country/city you've entered is " + temp_in_county_or_city + "°C.".decode('utf8').encode(local_encoding)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using python `f-string`, `f"{var}"`, you can use:

```py
theta = 45
print(f"Theta {theta}\N{DEGREE SIGN}.")
```

Output: `Theta 45°.`

*improving [tzot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216630/11671779)

Answer (score 0):

Special case:  Sending a string to a 16x2 or 20x4 LCD (e.g. attached to a Raspberry Pi with I2C LCD display):

```
f"Outside Temp: {my_temp_variable}{chr(223)}"
```