# Inserting a degree symbol into python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, symbols

This is a really simple problem but its escaping me. I'm just trying to insert a degree symbol into the titles and legends of my python plot. Code is below. Thanks.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta1 = linspace(0,60,610)
theta2 = linspace(0,45,460)
theta3 = linspace(45,90,460)

CTS = 1/cos(radians(theta1))
CTS0 = 1/cos(radians(60-theta2))
CTS45 = 1/cos(radians(105-theta3))

plt.plot(theta1,CTS,label=u'CTS Head at 0',linewidth=2)
plt.plot(theta2,CTS0,label='CTS Head at 60',linewidth=2)
plt.plot(theta3,CTS45,label='CTS Head at 105',linewidth=2)

plt.xlabel('Manufactured Ply Angle (degrees)')
plt.ylabel('Thickness')

plt.legend( loc='lower right', numpoints = 1 )
plt.ylim([0,2.5])

plt.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='both')
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
plt.axhline(y=1.035, xmin=0, xmax=90,color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use LaTeX Style. For Example: `$^\circ$ Text` would produce `°Text`

See the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) for more information about printing (especially mathematical expression).

In your case the code has to be: `plt.xlabel('Manufactured Ply Angle $^\circ$')`

The TeX part of the expression must be enclosed by dollar signs "$".

Answer (score 23):

Use LaTeX math.
On my system the best visual appearance is achieved with

`label = r'$45\degree$'`

and it looks exactly like the default theta labels of a polar plot.

As others have pointed out kludges like

- `label = r'$45^\circ$'`
- `label =  '$45^o$'`

etc. work too but the visual appearance is not so good.
On my system these workarounds render a symbol that is slightly too small.
YMMV, thus one may want to try what looks best on her system.

For example on a polar contour plot where radius is sine of zenith angle
one may want to use

```
deg_labels = np.array([5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 90])
ax.set_rgrids(np.sin(np.deg2rad(deg_labels)),     
              labels=(r"${:.0f}\degree$".format(_) for _ in deg_labels))
```

Comment: The example of the depiction of degrees in the example of numpy array labels in a polar contour plot (the one at the very end) was very helpful. Much appreciation! =)

Comment: `\degree` looks better than `^\circ`.

Answer (score 4):

Use degree unicode symbol, especially if you don't need LaTeX for other symbols.

U+00B0: `°`

In python3, it's just: `plt.xlabel("Manufactured Ply Angle (°)")`

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the answer given by dadaist, this also works for me to generate a degree symbol:

```
\N{degree sign}
```

so, in your example it would be

```
plt.xlabel('Manufactured Ply Angle (\N{degree sign})')
```

Comment: where does `\N` come from?

Comment: From escaping Unicode symbol names. See the first answer under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215168/how-to-get-character-in-a-string-in-python