# Displaying the Degree Symbol in Python

Tags: python

I've got the following code that displays the degree symbol and it works fine with Python3 in PyCharm:

```
print(u'\u00b0'+ " F")
```

But when I move the code over to Python3 on my Pi I get the following error:

> ```
> print(u'\u00b0'+ " F")
>               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Does anyone have any idea on why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: That seems to work for me. But see if this solution works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3216630/4933094

Comment: very helpful [How to get ° character in a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3215168/3904031)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python versions 3.0 through 3.2, the `u` prefix on a string literal was not allowed. Python 3.3 reintroduced it to aid in writing code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3 (see [PEP 414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/)).

I suspect your code is failing in one of the older versions of Python 3, and working on the other system in a newer version. In any version of Python 3, the `u` is unnecessary. You can just write `'\u00b0'+ " F"` or even `'\u00b0 F'` instead.