# Fail to rename columns because of character-encoding symbols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, character-encoding

I have a dataframe encoded in latin-1 and i want to rename a series of columns:

```
df=df.rename(columns={"DATE (YYYY-MM-DD)": 'local time',"AIR TEMP - DRY BULB HOURLY (°C)": 'air temp mean'...})
```

All other columns except of "AIR TEMP - DRY BULB HOURLY (°C)" and other column who has the superscript two symbol got their names changed and I think these last ones failed because of their symbols.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `&deg;C` and set the charset to `utf-8`.

Or look at this question, possible dublicate [How to get ° character in a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215168/how-to-get-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I prefered to work with the position of the column, was less laborious.